# R Markdown with Shiny Server change host parameter

Tags: shiny, rstudio, r-markdown, shiny-server

I am running RStudio on a server and I created a RMarkdown (.Rmd) file. It works fine if I create it as a static HTML but it does not work if I want it to be interactive (by adding *runtime:shiny*).

The issue is that when I add *runtime:shiny* and press the Run Document button the application will try to open at 127.0.0.1:xxxx (here xxxx is a random port). In order to make it work I would have to be able to change the host parameter to '0.0.0.0'. This is an option in the *runApp* function from the *shiny* package but I don't know how to add this option in *RMarkdown*.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `::run` command from `rmarkdown` invokes `shiny::runApp` internally. You can set the option `shiny.host` before running the document:

```
options(shiny.host="0.0.0.0")
rmarkdown::run("myfile.Rmd")
```

You an also pass arbitrary paramters to `runApp`, so this should work too:

```
rmarkdown::run("myfile.Rmd", shiny_args=list(host="0.0.0.0"))
```

Neither of these will work with the Run Document button; that button starts a new R session in which to render the document. To change the `shiny.host` option in that session, you'll need to add the option to your `.Rprofile`.

Answer (score 2):

Set the default values you want to initialize in (~/.Rprofile) under user directory

```
Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")  # for Timezone
options(shiny.port = 9999)
```